# How to use weights of a keras layer in calculating loss function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to build an autoencoder with only one layer:

```
from keras import backend as K

def cost2(y_true, y_pred):
    print "shapes:", model.get_weights()[0].shape
    yy = K.dot( y_pred, model.get_weights()[0].T )
    return np.sum((y_true - yy)**2)

x = Input(shape=(original_dim,))
y = Dense(latent_dim)(x)
model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=y)
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer='adagrad', loss=cost2)
```

This gives me error:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 784)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 1570      
=================================================================
Total params: 1,570
Trainable params: 1,570
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________

shapes: (784, 2)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vae_kears_gidital_mnist3.py", line 45, in 
    model.compile(optimizer='adagrad', loss=cost2)
  File "/Users/asgharrazavi/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 830, in compile
    sample_weight, mask)
  File "/Users/asgharrazavi/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 429, in weighted
    score_array = fn(y_true, y_pred)
  File "vae_kears_gidital_mnist3.py", line 18, in cost2
    yy = K.dot( y_pred, model.get_weights()[0].T )
  File "/Users/asgharrazavi/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 1048, in dot
    if ndim(x) is not None and (ndim(x) > 2 or ndim(y) > 2):
  File "/Users/asgharrazavi/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 606, in ndim
    dims = x.get_shape()._dims
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_shape'

I am simply trying to multiply output of model by the transpose weights of the model to get back to input dimensions.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your cost function should return a keras tensor not an `numpdy ndarray`. You should use only use `keras.backend` functions or your specific backend functions (e.g. `tf.something`) in the custome loss function (i.e. `K.sum` instead of `np.sum`)

This is the cause of the error you mentioned in the question but more importantly you're not making the model in *keras way* of creating autoencoders. In keras your model would be created with two layers (encoder and decoder) with layers sharing the weights with a transpose and a standard MSE loss. I suggest you read [this post](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html)
of keras blog and take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5060).